# Rails link_to image_tag works on Heroku but not locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm following Michael Hartl's Video tutorial and there one part that I'm confused about. I have to link an image on the home page.
So I thought the way it should be done is like this

```
<%= link_to image_tag('rails.png', alt: 'rails image'), http://google.ie %>
```

But this just gives me an error page, when I uploaded it to Heroku though it works fine, then if I change it to

```
<%= link_to image_tag('/assets/rails.png', alt: 'rails image'), http://google.ie %>
```

It works on both. Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I thought the first way was the correct way and Heroku seems to like it. I can't figure out why its not working locally though. I though once you ref the image name it should automatically look through the assets and images folder to find it

Comment: try asset_url -- link_to image_tag(asset_url('rails.png'), ....

Comment: Try using "double quotes" instead of 'single' -> `<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png") %>`

Comment: @RichPeck: Could you explain why we use `double quotes`? I'm curious

Comment: I had a problem some time ago where I used 'single quotes' and it messed up how rails evaluated the string. I've never recreated the issue; I found using "double quotes" solved it -- I now just use "double" rather than 'single' wherever the system needs to evaluate, or interpolate, a string

Comment: Thinking about it, I presume "double" quotes allows for interpolation/escaping, whereas 'single' treats the string literally

Answer (score 1):

Rails [link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) helper can take a block of code, for complex data inside a link element.

```
<%= link_to "http://google.ie" do %>
   <%= image_tag "rails.png", alt: "rails image" %>
<% - end -%>
```

Will produce

```
<a href='http://google.ie'>
   <img src='determined_with_asset_pipeline' alt='rails image'>
</a>
```